# What do I do if I get deranked in an unfair competitive game?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I recently got to *Gold Nova 1* and then I played a game with at least 2 people on the opposite side, wall and aim hacking. After, I got ranked down even though the game was unfair and we couldn't do anything about losing. Is there anyway I can get my rank back? If so, how?

**What can I do about this? Is there a way I can get the rank I deserve back? If so, how?**

Comment: As I understand the system, as long as you reported them, the match will be voided out if and or when they're banned

Comment: doest that mean i will get my original rank back or just get it cleared as a loss ?

Comment: I believe both. I'm not 100% certain though

Comment: You take it like a man. That is really the only thing you can do in the end.

Answer (score 8):

**What can I do about this?**

Unfortunately, the only thing you can really do about this is to **report the player** for cheating. There is nothing much a common player can do about these cheaters except to report them for cheating.

However, I would like to remind you to be absolutely certain that your opponent is cheating before doing so.

The developers of CS:GO have tried a multitude of ways in which to weed out cheaters. Most notably, is the existence of [CS:GO Overwatch](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/overwatch/). see the link for more information.

*In conclusion, while you can't expect to get your opponent banned for sure, you can be certain that if he were cheating, he will be caught sooner or later. Justice will be served.*

**How about my rank? Can I get it back?**

In the case of an opponent being banned, after being reported for that particular match, the match would be considered **null and void.** It would no longer carry any weight in determining your ranks.

Party members of your opponents and your entire team would have their **ranks and ELO points adjusted** to their appropriate value.

*In short, should that player be found cheating in that particular match, yes, your rank will essentially be "reset".*

***Just a friendly tip...***

*I would like to end off by telling you to expect to run into cheaters often. The CS:GO community has always been littered with them. In your case, you are a mere Gold Nova 1. When you reach the higher ranks, especially above Legendary Eagle Master, cheaters are abundant every 3 or so games.*

*Take it from me I have been there and all I can say is, half the time, I would just have to live with the fact that those players are likely to go unpunished.*

*Even if you were to lose your rank and not get it back, do not be disheartened everyone faces cheaters but eventually, we all get the rank we deserve.*

Comment: "every 3 or so games" a cheater would mean that there is statistically one cheater every 30 players (27 if you do not count yourself), would mean a ratio of 3 or 4 percent. I don't know the exact number at the moment since there has been done much (Ban waves, rank system...), but I can say that the number is even higher in this elo. In the lower ranks there is also the problem of very many so-called _smurfs_ (High-skilled players, who create a new account to get matched with lower-skilled people in order that they can play with less effort more sucessfully)

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 I am currently at SMFC. You may be surprised to hear that even at this rank, there is a lack of BLATANT cheaters. (e.g. straight up aimbots etc.) This is because most of them get banned before they get to this rank. However, I definitely believe that a lot of players at my rank cheat. Albeit more SUBTLY. Whatever the case, with no blatant cheaters, it is not impossible to win games. So while there are several more subtle cheaters at my rank, they are not unbeatable. But once every 3 or so games, there is one guy that is blatantly hacking and is basically unstopable.

Comment: OK so you talked about the obvious cases, allright. Then I don't know the correct number, however before the great ban waves and the introduction of the rank system occured, there were at least 20% users of third-party software, what - of-course - means that they can't be beaten by mere skills.